# Check Time Range Lapse in Other Time Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a Time In and Time Out and there is a time range defined for Lunch Breakfast and Dinner. What i want is to Subtract these times from the attendance time (Time In And Time Out).

The sample data is

Attendance Table Data

```
EMPID 1095

TimeIN  2017-03-01 08:52:45.000

TimeOut 2017-03-01 19:59:18.000
```

The Mess Timings are

```
type    StartTime   EndTime
BreakFast   06:30:39    10:00:39
Dinner  19:00:39    21:00:39
Lunch   12:00:23    15:00:23
```

What i need is to subtract these mess timings from the actual attendance time to get actual employee duty time.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, can you have multiple Time-In and time-out for the day? Or is it fixed with 1 time in, 1 time out per day

Comment: Or even harder - timeIn on one day, and timeOut on the next (like in a night shift)?

Comment: Well i have already sorted that out time in and out are single time entry.

Comment: How specific does this need to be?  To the nearest minute or second?

Answer (score 0):

This approach utilises a numbers table to create a lookup table of all the seconds between your `@TimeIn` and `@TimeOut` values.  This will work for periods covering multiple days, albeit with some severe caveats:

- Breakfast, Lunch and Dinner are at the same time every day.
- Your `@TimeIn` and `@TimeOut` period doesn't get so big it overflows the `int` value that contains the number of `seconds`.

  - In that case you will need to either just use `minutes` or find a different method
- Your return value is less than 24 hours.

  - In that case, just don't return the difference as a `time` data type and handle it accordingly.

---

```
declare @TimeIn datetime    = '2017-03-01 08:52:45.000'
        ,@TimeOut datetime  = '2017-03-01 19:59:18.000'

        ,@BStart time       = '06:30:39'
        ,@BEnd time         = '10:00:39'
        ,@LStart time       = '12:00:23'
        ,@LEnd time         = '15:00:23'
        ,@DStart time       = '19:00:39'
        ,@DEnd time         = '21:00:39';

-- Create numbers table then use it to build a table os seconds between TimeIn and TimeOut
with n(n) as (select n from (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) as n(n))
    ,s(s) as (select top (select datediff(s,@TimeIn,@TimeOut)+1) dateadd(s,row_number() over (order by (select 1))-1,@TimeIn) from n n1,n n2,n n3,n n4,n n5,n n6)
select cast(dateadd(s,count(1),0) as time) as s
from s
where s between @TimeIn and @TimeOut    -- Return all seconds that aren't within Breakfast, Lunch or Dinner
    and cast(s as time) not between @BStart and @BEnd
    and cast(s as time) not between @LStart and @LEnd
    and cast(s as time) not between @DStart and @DEnd
```

Which returns: `05:59:58.0000000`

Answer (score 0):

I have daily timings of mess in other table so i created a view  and took all fields in front of daily attendance then using case statement to match the timings with Daily Attendance Time.

```
EmployeeID  AttendanceDate  ShiftID TimeIn  TimeOut BreakOut    BreakIn LeaveType   TotalHours  LeaveHours  ATOThours   DeductedHrs OTHours UserID  AudtDate    Reason  SM  SY  OTDed   DutyDed Mark    Expr1   MARKL   BreakFastStart  BreakFastEnd    LunchStart  LunchEnd    DinnerStart DinnerEnd
1095    2017-03-01 00:00:00.000 1   2017-03-01 08:52:45.000 2017-03-01 19:59:18.000 NULL    NULL    NULL    0   NULL    0   0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    3   2017    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2017-02-20 06:30:34.000 2017-02-20 09:30:34.000 2017-02-20 12:00:26.000 2017-02-20 15:00:26.000 2017-02-20 19:00:59.000 2017-02-20 21:00:59.000
```

For now it's good will check it's credibility with the passage of time.

Thanks For the support

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following script in the View OR in JOIN query of the tables. Note I got a different answer which I think is correct.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ss, 
        (DATEDIFF(ss,TimeIn, [TimeOut]) -
         (
            DATEDIFF(ss,[BreakFastStartTime], [BreakFastEndTime]) + 
            DATEDIFF(ss,[LunchStartTime], [LunchEndTime]) +
            DATEDIFF(ss,[DinnerStartTime], [DinnerEndTime]) 
         )
        ), 0), 108) 
FROM [Attendance Data]
```

For your example, answer is `02:36:33`